# Detect Internet Connection in Android Application?

Tags: android, android-networking

I have following method, which will check for the Internet connection in the device :

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = 
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

But after a while I found out that this method only checks for the Network Connectivity; like the device is connected to a router and the router is ON but no internet is available, this method returns true.

So How to know that there is actual internet or not ?

Answer (score 4):

So what is 'actual internet'? The ability to connect to any possible host on the Internet at any given time? A bit hard to test, no? Try connecting to a well-known server (Google, NASA, your country's top provider home page), and if it works, you probably have 'actual Internet'.

Comment: I would go a bit farther and say its best to check if you can connect to a dedicated IP address, such as google's static, and not rely on DNS to do the lookups.

Comment: Yes, but if DNS is broken, the whole thing is not of much use, right?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see for you is trying to connect to a website like google and if you get result then you can be sure of it, else no internet activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this function...

```
public static Boolean checknetwork(Context mContext) 
    {

        NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) 
        {

            return false;
        }
        if (info.isRoaming()) 
        {
            // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
            // disable internet while roaming, just return false
            return true;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of questions already on this topic with answers with suggested solution. Try taking a look at some of these.

[Check Network Coverage in Android before trying to send SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275663/check-network-coverage-in-android-before-trying-to-send-sms)

[How to check internet access (INCLUDING tethering!) on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474205/how-to-check-internet-access-including-tethering-on-android)

[How to determine the network unavailability in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227071/how-to-determine-the-network-unavailability-in-android)